# How to get the solution $x = 5$ of $x^2 = 9 \bmod 16$ from solutions modulo $8$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

By brute force I know all solutions of $x^2 =9 \bmod 16$ are $\{3, 5, 11, 13\}$.  I'm interested in the well-known procedure of lifting solutions modulo $8$ to solutions modulo $16$.

I find $r \in \{1, 3, 5, 7\}$ are all solutions of $x^2 = 9 \bmod 8$. I use these solutions to lift them to solutions modulo $16$, but difficulties arise.  I find that $r = 1$ and $r = 7$ cannot be lifted because their linear congruences --- that define $q$ from which we get solutions $a = r + 8q \bmod 16$ --- have no solutions.  So far so good.  From $r = 3$, I get $q \in \{3, 7\}$ that produce solutions $\{3, 11\}$.  So far so good.  Now from $r = 5$, I get $q \in \{3, 7\}$, both of which produce only the solution $13$.

I'm missing solution $5$.

Should I have found it or is there no guarantee that I can do all possible lifting and find all desired solutions?

**Debugging the case $r = 5$**.  I'll describe my steps in details for the lifting of $r = 5\bmod 8$.  Since $f'(x) = 2x$, $f'(5) = 10$.  Also, $f(5) = 5^2 - 9 = 25 - 9 = 16$ and $k_5 = f(5)/8 = 2$.  I know the solutions I'm looking for are $a = r + 8q \bmod 16$, but I must find $q$.  I find $q$ by solving $qf'(5) + k_5 = 0 \bmod 8$, that is, $10q + 2 = 0 \bmod 8$ whose solutions are $q \in \{3, 7\}$ which produce solutions $a = 5 + 8\times3 = 13 \bmod 16$ and $a = 5 + 8\times7 = 13 \bmod 16$.

Comment: 1,7 give nothing. 3 gives 3,11. 5 gives 5,13

Comment: Here's what I find, having checked and rechecked.  Clearly $f'(x) = 2x$, so $f'(5) = 10$.  Also $f(5) = 5^2 - 9 = 25 - 9 = 16$ and $f(5)/8$... Wait, wait, wait.  I think I just made a mistake.  Should I divide $f(5)$ by $8$ or by $2$?  I have been dividing by $8$ and getting lucky answers perhaps.  Dividing by $2$ now did yield solutions $\{5, 13\}$ as expected.  Maybe I've been lucky so far because I've considered mostly going from congruences mod $p$ to congruences mod $p^2$.

Comment: To debug your work we need to see what you did. But you have not given *full* details.

Comment: I added full details for the case $r = 5$.  I hope that shows my wrong turn.  Thank you.

Comment: $\bmod 4\!:\ x^2\equiv 9\equiv 1\iff x\equiv \color{#c00}1,3.\,$ so lifting the first root $\,x = \color{#c00}1+4j\,$ yields $\bmod 16\!:\ 9\equiv x^2\equiv (\color{#c00}1\!+\!4j)^2\equiv 1\!+\!8j\iff 8j\equiv 8\iff \color{#0a0}{j\equiv 1\pmod{\!2}}\,$ so this root lifts to  $ x =  1\!+\!4\color{#0a0}j = 1\!+\!4(\color{#0a0}{1\!+\!2n}) = 5+8n\equiv 5,13\pmod{\!16}.\,$ Similarly the root $\,x\equiv 3\pmod{\!4}\,$ lifts to $\,3+8n\equiv 3,11\pmod{\!16}$. To debug your work it would help if you posted the precise statement of the (Hensel?) lifting theorem you are using.

Comment: Hi.  Did you mean to write modulo $16$ on your second line?  The theorem I'm using really looks like Hensel's, but [in the writing of Apostol](https://i.postimg.cc/rpYSC09M/image.png).

Comment: You are in case $(b_1)$ of the theorem, which implies that the root $\,r = 5 + 8q\,$ lifts to $p=2$ roots $\bmod 16$ (viz $\,q = 0,1\,$ yields roots $5,13).\,$  Note: you need to write <atsign>Bill for me be notified by your comment (<Tab> does username completion). Else I may never see it.